# How to prove this equation $W_b= {P_2V_2 - P_1V_1 \over 1-n}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

$W_b = \int$Pdv

$PV^{n}$=C

$P=CV^{-n}$

W=$\int cv^{-n} $dv

=c$\int_{v1}^{v2}V^{-n}$ dv

=c[${v^{-n+1} \over 1-n}]_{v1}^{v2}$

How to get rid of the (-n+1)?

to prove $W_b= {P_2V_2 - P_1V_1 \over 1-n}$

Comment: Please try to come up with a more descriptive title.

Comment: Gee, that's a toughie

Comment: sorry, i am dumb, lol~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the integration by applying the limits in the sixth equation.
Multiply by c.
Substitute $P=cV^{-n}$ twice.